# Key-up event in Emacs, or poll keyboard state?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs is there is a way to check for a key-up event, or, alternatively, is it possible to poll the keyboard and check if a key is currently pressed?

Comment: Can't you just register it as a hotkey in ELISP, what exactly do you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: I too am curious about why you would need this. It seems unusual to me to be holding down any keys in Emacs.

Comment: I'm attempting to port a non-standard keymapping (PinkyTwirl https://github.com/JordanFisher/PinkyTwirl). A lot of the maps in PinkyTwirl are like 3-j (Hold 3 and press j).  
I can sort of implement this in emacs using chords (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/key-chord.el), which recognizes when two keys are pressed simultaneously, or with some lag between them. I can set the lag period such that I can hold 3 for a while before I have to press j, which works great. The problem is what happens if I press 3 and then let go? That should just insert 3 into the buffer. I need an up event to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs elisp API don't allow you get info how long key pressed and if it still currently pressed.

Emacs work not only in GUI mode but also in terminals, where this info is not available (as hardware don't support it).

So GNU Emacs written in way that it can not pull such info to you.

If you want more complete answer ask on *emacs-devel@gnu.org* but be careful do not be offtopic. *help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org* is primary list for Emacs questions.

Also check: [EmacsMailingLists](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMailingLists) [EmacsNewsgroups](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewsgroups)

StackOverflow is not good site for question about Emacs internals...